# need captcha in my custom WordPress form

Tags: wordpress, captcha

I want a captcha in my WordPress custom form like this:-[image]

Is there a plugin available which will allow me to add this type of captcha?

Answer (score 1):

http://safesrv.net/adding-recaptcha-to-a-contact-form-page-on-wordpress/#comment-5389

i got the reference from this....

Answer (score 0):

Try reCAPTCHA  for custom form.

Refer http://wordpress.org/support/topic/recaptcha-on-custom-html-form

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-form-manager/

Comment: hello @vinod VT , i refered this but i want in my custom form ,how can i add captcha in my custom form?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin allows you to implement super security captcha form into web forms.
Have a look at [this link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/)